# How can I apply custom style to the dropdown object that ui-select creates dynamically?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm working on a single page application that uses **AngularJS v1.5.8.** I'm trying to make a simple visual change but can't find how to do it.

There's a `<ui-select>` dropdown object that populates from a list that comes from the backend. It works correctly but I need to make the dropdown a little bigger. I've been trying to assign a CSS class to the resulting dropdown with no success. The style I apply to the ui-select object doesn't seem to be applied to the div that is the dropdown itself.

The ui-select directive creates a `<span>` with the ID "ui-devtype-span". When I manually edit this object style (like in Chrome developer tools) I get the result I wanted. But this span object doesn't exist in my code. It seems to be generated dynamically and it doesn't inherit the style from ui-select. The theme is "bootstrap"

```
<ui-select theme="bootstrap"
               ng-model="..."
               on-select="..."
               ng-disabled="..."
               append-to-body="true">
         <ui-select-match allow-clear="" >
          <span >
            {{$select.selected.name}}
          </span>
        </ui-select-match>
      <ui-select-choices
        repeat="group in ...
                 | orderBy: 'name'
                 | filter: $select.search">
        <span ng-bind-html="group.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
      </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

I tried adding my css class to every HTML tag in this fragment but I could not get the dynamically generated `<span>` to be 45px high. I cannot change the directive style in a broader way because it's used elsewhere in the application, and my change should apply to this screen only.

Comment: Does the span have an *ID* of `ui-devtype-span` of a *class* of `ui-devtype-span`?

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot change the directive style in a broader way because it's used elsewhere in the application,

Then give the directive an `id`.

```
<ui-select id="select1" theme="bootstrap" ng-model="..."
```

And us a [descendent combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator)

```
<style>
   #select1 span {
      font-size: 20px;
   }
</style>
```

OR add a custom class:

```
<ui-select class="my-select" theme="bootstrap" ng-model="..."

<style>
   .my-select span {
      font-size: 20px;
   }
</style>
```